# Mac: How to see list of running network services?

Tags: macos, networking, midi, nsnetservice

I am writing an application that needs to connect with a running network service on a Mac.

Problem is, I have no idea what the service is called or even what port it uses. Is there a way to browse all running network services on my Mac?

More info:

- I am connecting to a MIDI network session (found under 'Audio MIDI settings', present on all OSX installs). Am I correct in thinking this is a network service?
- I am planning to use NSNetServiceBrowser to locate all local computers running this service. (is this the best way to go about it?)

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From:

> "...no idea what the service is called or
>   even what port it uses..."

try in terminal:

```
nc 192.168.1.30 1-9999
```

Replace 192.168.1.30 by your ip, and replace 1-9999 to the port range you want to scan. 1-9999 would mean scan from port 1 to 9999.
2. From:

> "...network services on my Mac..."

Try Bonjour Browser.
http://www.tildesoft.com/

Just a humble suggestion.

Comment: `lsof` can also be helpful, specifically, `lsof -i` (run as `root`).

Answer (score 2):

The ***Network Utility*** found under *Applications/Utilities* has an option to Port Scan a host, running against **`localhost`** will show you what ports are open for connections.

Comment: Cool, this works too :) In this case though, Bonjour Browser was the best solution as it shows the 'type' of netservice that I'll need to know when I'm connecting, i.e. it shows the type as "_apple-midi._udp."